# How to format dates in R

Tags: r, date

I'm having trouble changing date format in R.  I have a vector `"StartDate"` with dates and time for instance in the format:

```
01Feb1991 00:00
```

I did:

```
as.POSIXct(as.character(bio$StartDate), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

...but I got `NA`s as a result. Would there be a different way to change the vector into date format?

Answer (score 2):

The format you provide has to match your string. In your case, that's '%d%b%Y %H:%M' (you don't have slashes between day, month and year, and your month is the abbreviated name, not the number).

```
as.POSIXct('01Feb1991 00:00', format='%d%b%Y %H:%M')
```

See `?strptime` (mentioned in `?as.POSIXct`) for various tokens you can use for dates.